# Doesn't it make more sense to wrap hot sandwiches with the foil facing in?

Tags: food, heating, food-storage, thermal-regulation

You know those hot sandwiches sold in grocery stores (northeast USA at least...) that are wrapped in a foil paper? Wouldn't it thermally make more sense to have the shiny foil facing in? To keep the heat reflected inside the sandwich?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The foil / paper lamination creates air pockets between the layers that retain heat. Also the paper side absorbs some moisture and oils to attempt to keep it from getting soggy

Comment: that's answer enough for me! Makes sense. I guess technically if there's a shiny side of the foil, even on the other side of the paper, this would still have a heat-retention effect huh

Comment: You could add that both sides have essentially the same reflectivity for infrared radiaton ([Pozzobon et al](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337390826_Household_aluminum_foil_matte_and_bright_side_reflectivity_measurements_Application_to_a_photobioreactor_light_concentrator_design) ).